# Insert data partially into a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert into my table something with partial data and leaving the rest default but somehow it keeps saying wrong syntax

[image]

My query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO day 
    (1030, 1100, date, tech) 
    VALUES ('356-635-3633', '356-635-3633', '2019-04-07', 'Thy')
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1030, 1100, date, tech) VALUES('356-635-3633', '356-635-3633', '2019-04-07', 'Th' at line 1

A query like this works though:

```
INSERT INTO day (date, tech) VALUES ('2019-04-07', 'Thy')
```

*The datatype for all those columns are varchar(30)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to quotes these all-digits identifiers, using backticks;

```
INSERT INTO day 
    (`1030`, `1100`, date, tech) 
    VALUES ('356-635-3633', '356-635-3633', '2019-04-07', 'Thy')
```

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html):

> Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cT31af3AMpPG83J21FiNTT/0)** (you can uncomment the original column list to generate the error).

NB: `day` and  `date` correspond to names of MySQL functions. Using them like you do do not generate error, but it would still be a good idea to surround them with backticks a well, just to avoid any ambiguity, hence:

```
INSERT INTO `day`
    (`1030`, `1100`, `date`, tech) 
    VALUES ('356-635-3633', '356-635-3633', '2019-04-07', 'Thy')
```